# Prove that $(a^2 + 1)(b^2 + 1)(c^2 + 1) \ge (a + b)(b + c)(c + a)$ for $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

How to prove that $(a^2 + 1)(b^2 + 1)(c^2 + 1) \ge (a + b)(b + c)(c + a)$ for $a, b,  c \in \mathbb{R}$ ? I have tried AM-GM but with no effect.

Comment: what else is given?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Cauchy inequality we have:

$$(a^2 + 1)(1+b^2) \ge (a + b)^2$$
$$(a^2 + 1)(1+c^2) \ge (a + c)^2$$
$$(c^2 + 1)(1+b^2) \ge (c + b)^2$$

Multiply these and take square root and thus the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
(abc-1)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{perms} a^2(b-1)^2 \geq 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Hello @DonaltdSplutterwit, does $\displaystyle\sum_{perms}$ mean $\displaystyle\sum_{cyc}$?

Comment: @DenizTunaYalçın $ \sum_{cyc} $ means cyclic permute the terms and usually has three terms. $ \sum_{perms} $ means all permutations and usually has six terms. (in the $3$ variable case.) 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{cyc} a^2(b^2-1)& =& a^2(b^2-1) +b^2(c^2-1) +c^2(a^2-1) \\
\sum_{perms} a^2(b^2-1) &=& a^2(b^2-1) +b^2(a^2-1) +b^2(c^2-1) +c^2(b^2-1)+c^2(a^2-1)+a^2(c^2-1).
\end{eqnarray*}
I do mean perms in this instant.

Comment: I didn't know the difference, I do know:) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By C-S we obtain:
$$\prod_{cyc}(a^2+1)=\sqrt{\prod_{cyc}(a^2+1)(1+b^2)}\geq\sqrt{\prod_{cyc}(a+b)^2}=$$
$$\geq\left|\prod_{cyc}(a+b)\right|\geq\prod_{cyc}(a+b)$$
and we are done!